# How can I combine several plots generated in one output?

Tags: plotting

Say I define a function to create plots

```
plots[i_]:=Plot[x^i,{x,0,1}]
```

And that I generate many plots in one output

```
Do[Print[plots[i]],{i,1,10}]
```

How can I combine the 10 plots I get using the function Show? (or anthing that works similarly)

Comment: `Show @@ Table[plots[i], {i, 1, 10}]`

Comment: Show[Table[plots[i],{i,1,10}]]

Comment: Use `Show[Table...]` instead of the loop. It will make the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
plots[n_] := Plot[Table[x^i, {i, n}], {x, 0, 1}]
plots[8]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Consider `..Evaluate @ Table ..`.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot it. It reminded me that I have to use Evaluate @ Table sometimes. I have tried a couple of different functions, it seems that Evaluate is unnecessary in this case . f[x_] := Sin[x] + Cos[x];
plots[n_] := Plot[Table[f[i x], {i, n}], {x, 0, 1}];
plots[8]